# Method Not Allowed while doing Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

## Route

```
Route::put('url/update',['as'=>'test.update', 'uses'=>'TestController@update']);
```

---

## Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/update',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $inputs ,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('PUT error.', xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

---

## Result

```
PUT http://localhost:80/url/update 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Comment: Does `$device_mac` have any spaces or illegal URL characters in it?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a space in it. Why do I have a space somewhere ?

Comment: Check exactly the URL you are getting inside the `$.ajax`.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you do a `console.log()` of the URL and/or look in the network tab of the debugger and see exactly what request URL is being sent over the wire.

Comment: `Request URL:http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/device/080027E2FC7D` Keep cutting off my last 2 segments.

Comment: It should be Request `URL:http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/device/080027E2FC7D/rate/update`

Comment: Try using Laravel to build out the URL.  `url: {{ route('device.rate.update', [env("APP_URL"), $cpe_mac, $device_mac] }},`

Comment: @user3158900 : This doesn't work either. Your code missing a closing `)`

Comment: If you are generating the js code within blade, show us the generated HTML with the jQuery function.

Comment: I'd suggest you do a View/Source in the browser to see what this ajax code source looks like in the actual generated Javascript.  Then, you can figure out whether your problem is before or after that and narrow down the search.

Comment: @azeós : I've added my HTML form that generated by **blade**.

Comment: But you are missing the jQuery part, that's what we need to see. Or do what @jfriend00 suggest.

Comment: @jfriend00 : Is it because I PUT a `defected` JSON ?

Comment: @azeós : jQuery Part added

Comment: That jQuery is what you have inside the blade file. What we need to see is the result of that, the HTML output. Do a view source as @jfriend00 said, copy the jQuery part and paste it here.

Comment: are you using laravel 5 or laravel 5.1?  Unless you're using both versions, you shouldn't include both tags.

Comment: @Stan Additional `laravel-5.1` added to specify version, you can see in tag info _5.1 version of Laravel framework. Use it in addition to the laravel-5 tag if your question is specific to Laravel 5.1._.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki there are three tags: "laravel", "laravel 5" and "laravel 5.1".  I would think that either "laravel" and "laravel 5" OR "laravel" and "laravel 5.1" should be included, unless he is using both versions 5 and 5.1?  Isn't that like tagging ".Net", ".Net 4.0" and ".Net 4.5"?  I think I'm misunderstanding how to properly use tags, here?

Comment: I think what @user3158900 suggested is almost right. `url: '{{ route('device.rate.update', [$cpe_mac, $device_mac]) }}'`. Try that.

Comment: @azeós : Still get `PUT http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/device/080027E2FC7D 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Then please show us the generated HTML.

Comment: If you change your `url: ...` section to `url: '{{ url("/".$cpe_mac."/device/".$device_mac."/rate/update") }}'` does it affect anything? I have never tried using `env("APP_URL")`, it looks odd to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method to 'POST' and add a hidden element '_method' with value set to 'PUT' in the form.

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631237/2507790
- http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: Good answer, I suspect this is the problem.

Comment: I agree with you. Update my route to POST, and update my Ajax `type: 'POST',`, and still the same result.

Comment: Did I miss anything else beside  that 2 thing ?

Comment: Can you check in the network logs if '_method' is being passed in the request ?

Comment: I got `_method: "PUT"` in my Request Payload Section.

Comment: Actually if you just change the ajax to POST and leave everything as it is, should still be a PUT request because of the method spoofing. What you are missing is the HTML code :p

Comment: Your Route should still be PUT not POST,  just change AJAX's type( or method ) POST.

Comment: Where do you get that most browsers don't support PUT requests on Ajax calls?

Comment: @jfriend00 check [this](https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/) , it's not much authentic but after reading it and the error "405 (Method Not Allowed)" faced by OP, it makes sense.

Comment: I just tried a "PUT" ajax request in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 to my own server and it worked just fine.  There is no browser restriction on using PUT requests via Ajax.  It works.  It's also documented on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).  So, the first sentence of your answer is just wrong.  I have no idea if the OP has some sort of server issue with a PUT request or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my comment was not correct because I was not looking close enough at the structure.  I'm pretty sure it would work if modified though.

I just setup the following route:

```
Route::put('{cpe_mac}/device/{device_mac}/rate/update', [ 'as'=> 'device.rate.update', 'uses' => 'DeviceController@updateRate']);
```

I added the javascript to the view:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('device.rate.update', [$cpe_mac, $device_mac], true) }}',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
        some: 'test'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

I'm passing `true` as the 3rd argument so it builds a URL with an absolute path.  I think it's a bit cleaner than trying to prepent `env("APP_URL")`.

The result on the page was:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myapp.local/000D6766F2F6/device/080027E2FC7D/rate/update',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
        some: 'test'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Comment: That is very strange!  It worked exactly as intended for me and I thought for sure this would help you.  Sorry, and good luck!

Comment: I really appreciated your help.

Comment: My Ajax is success POST now, how do I access in my controller ? Do you know how ?

Comment: What are you trying to access in your controller?

Comment: The data that I post using Ajax.

Comment: Yeah that should be all described at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms only support GET and POST, but it does understand a real PUT/PATCH request.

Other Notes:
1. Use Postman first to check your API.
1. Make sure your protocol is http / https.
1. Your Controller method should return JSON Format.
1. Make sure your received your inputs.

Refer to this Answer for few more info:
http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-i-can-not-get-inputs-from-a-putpatch-request-

Comment: I got new error, feel free to take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/q/34340304/4480164