# 500 Internal Server Error Ajax Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a POST to

`http://localhost:8888/test`

---

**JS**

```
$('.saveBTN').click(function (event) {

    $( "form#editForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var inputs = {};
      $("#editForm :input").each(function() {
        inputs[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
      });

      var $inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs);

      $.ajax({
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
          url: '/test',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: $inputs,
          success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

              console.log(data);
          },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              console.log('PUT error.');
          }
      });

});
```

---

I keep getting

> 500 Internal Server Error

I've tried added

`<meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

and this on my Ajax

`headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},`

Any hints on this will be much appreciated !

Comment: Fire up the inspector have a look at the full details of the 500 response that would give you a better idea of what is going on. A guess is routing you say PUT error in your error handling but are making a POST request are you looking for a PUT on your route?

Comment: What does your routing look like?

Comment: can you check the log file in storage folder for error stack?

Comment: 500 error means the script on the server is getting an error. Check your server log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this in below inside the form.

```
// This will generate token field which will be token
{{ csrf_field() }}  


// Expected Output
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="ssdfdsfsdfsdfs32r23442">
```

`VerifyCsrfToken.php` - The File is `middleware`, which is included in the web middleware group, will automatically verify that the `token` in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

Refer this URL for few more information:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

> Updates - 23rd Dec 2016

As of laravel, you can use like below as well.

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

API Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 0):

Like **@Paulpro** and **@Mark Davidson** mentioned in comments bellow the `meta` tag should have `content` attribute and not value :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Instead of :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Hope this helps.