# Laravel AJAX PUT update request only works in localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-file-upload, php-7

I can't figure out why this block of code only works on my localhost, in my production server the requests goes through and $request->input() returns an empty array but in my localhost it works perfectly fine. Both on version php7. Any thoughts ?

```
var formData = new FormData($('#postSliderFrm')[0]);

if(imagePicked)
    formData.append('file',imagePicked);

formData.append('_method', 'put');

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '{{route('dashboard.admin.sliders.update', $slider->id)}}',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
```

I've also tried adding

```
{!! method_field('put') !!}
```

inside my form but still no luck

Comment: Cos your localhost post max size is more than 2 MB i guess. By default apache handles data worth only of 2MB.

Comment: What kind of response do you get from the server? (browser console->network->click on the request; Or something along these lines depending on the browser you're using)

Answer (score 2):

**[Method not allowed when PUT used over AJAX for Laravel resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631206/method-not-allowed-when-put-used-over-ajax-for-laravel-resource)**: Take a look at that, it might be better to use GET or more commonly POST to handle this, do you specifically NEED to use PUT?

Comment: The linked question here shows the answer.  You need to [spoof a PUT request in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing).  Replace ` type: 'PUT',` with POST, and include `method_field('put')` as you have.

Comment: I'm using PUT because I'm using Laravel's CRUD resource. Are there any difference performance-wise PUT vs POST ?

Comment: @user3364008 Theres plently of information about them on stackoverflow, heres a really good example -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request**

Comment: @Don'tPanic wow thanks ! that fixed my problem ! can't believe the fix was that easy but it was strange that it worked on my localhost