# Laravel 5.4 not able to parse FormData javascript object sent using Jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, http, laravel-5.4, form-data

Lately I've been trying to solve an issue with no luck, basically I'm trying to submit a form to the server using AJAX, the form has files, so I'm using the `FormData` javascript object in JQuery 1.12. The data arrives to the server but in I way I don't know how to format it.

This is my AJAX function:

```
function saveMenu(id){
    var formElement = document.getElementById("menu-form");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.append('_method', 'PUT');
    $( "#form-wrapper" ).toggleClass( "be-loading-active" );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: "{{url('myUrl')}}",
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            toastr.success('Yai! Saved successfully!')
        },
        error: function(response) {
            toastr.error('Oh oh! Something went really wrong!')
        },
        complete: function() {
            $( "#form-wrapper" ).toggleClass( "be-loading-active" )
        }
    });
}
```

and when I perform a `dd($request->all());` in my controller I get something like this:

```
array:1 [
  "------WebKitFormBoundaryRCIAg1VylATQGx46\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name" => """
    "_token"\r\n
    \r\n
    jtv4bnn8WQnP3eqmKZV3xWka2YOpnNc1pgrIfk0D\r\n
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryRCIAg1VylATQGx46\r\n
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="blocks[43][title]"\r\n
    \r\n
...
```

Things I've tried:

- Set the HTTP verb to POST. Same result.
- Set the AJAX `contentType: false`, `contentType: application/json`. Empty response.
- Remove `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'`. Same response.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.. ill try to make a workable instance in my place. did you try this dd($request->_method)?

Comment: @RomnickSusa Yes, it returns null.

Comment: did you remove js cache after removing `nctype: 'multipart/form-data` because I think it is key

Comment: @ThomasMoors In my case it looks the same.

Comment: if you're not using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0. , you should change the ` type: 'PUT'` to ` method: 'PUT'`

Comment: @Onix Im using Jquery 1.12, sorry I'll update the question

Comment: type = post + data: _method = put? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631206/method-not-allowed-when-put-used-over-ajax-for-laravel-resource

Comment: @ThomasMoors I've already tried to change the verb to POST and I got the same response. IMO it's nothing to do with the client-server communication but with the js object.

Comment: OMG, I found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I gave up trying to make it work and tried a more vanilla approach, I still don't know the reason why the request is formated like that, but the `XMLHttpRequest()` function works perfectly and the migration is not a big deal.

The equivalent of the function I posted about would be:

```
function saveMenu(action){
    var formElement = document.getElementById("menu-form");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "{{url('myUrl')}}");
    request.send(formData);

    request.onload = function(oEvent) {
      if (request.status == 200) {
        toastr.success('Yai! Saved successfully!');
      } else {
        toastr.error('Oh oh! Something went really wrong!');
      }
      $( "#form-wrapper" ).toggleClass( "be-loading-active" );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me

```
data: form_data,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

`processData: false` prevents jQuery from parsing the data and throwing an Illegal Invocation error. JQuery does this when it encounters a file in the form and can not convert it to string (serialize it).

`contentType: false` prevents ajax sending the content type header. The content type header make Laravel handel the FormData Object as some serialized string.

setting both to false made it work for me.
I hope this helps.

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var api_token = $('meta[name="api-token"]').attr('content');
        form_data = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/v1/item/add',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + api_token
            },
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result,status,xhr) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

also remember to use `$request->all();` `$request->input()` excludes the files

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to debug that for 2 hours and i found out that method PUT is not working with formData properly.

Try changing

```
type : "PUT"
```

into

```
method : "POST"
```

Then change your method on your backend from `put` to `post` and you'll see the difference. 
I used below codes to test it

```
$("#menu-form").submit(function (){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('section', 'general');
    fd.append('action', 'previewImg');
    fd.append('new_image', $('.new_image')[0].files[0]); 
    $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token()}}'
        },
        url: "{{url('upload-now')}}",
        data : fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

And in my controller

```
public function test(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Ill try to research more about this issue.

Comment: Sorry but my form is more complex than just 3 inputs you can comfortably append, it has multiple levels and more files. Anyway I've tried to change to the POST method as I said in the question and it didn't changed for me.

Comment: I'll revise my answer later

Comment: I have a solution, but I discarted jquery ajax function in favor of `XMLRequest()`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 7,
if use method PUT in ajax, you can follow
1. change method `method: 'PUT'` to `method: 'POST'` 
2. add formdata.append with _method PUT like this example :

```
$('#updateBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $('#tambahForm');
    frm.trigger("reset");
    $('.edit_errorNama_kategori').hide();
    $('.edit_errorGambar').hide();
    var url = "/pengurus/category/"+$('#edit_id').val();
    var formdata = new FormData($("#editForm")[0]);
    formdata.append('_method', 'PUT');  //*** here

    $.ajax({                       
        method :'POST', //*** here
        url : url,
        data : formdata,
        dataType : 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data){
          if (data.errors) {
            if (data.errors.nama_kategori) {
                $('.edit_errorNama_kategori').show();
                $('.edit_errorNama_kategori').text(data.errors.nama_kategori);
            }
            if (data.errors.gambar){
              $('.edit_errorGambar').show();
              $('.edit_errorGambar').text(data.errors.gambar);
            }
          }else {
            frm.trigger('reset');
            $('#editModal').modal('hide');
            swal('Success!','Data Updated Successfully','success');
            table.ajax.reload(null,false);
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Please Reload to read Ajax');
          console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
});
```

its works for me

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but;
This will solve your problem;

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
console.log(...formData);

var object = {};
formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
    object[key] = value;
});
```

Then you can send this `object` to the server. This is much more readable and works great.

OR

You can simply send this directly;

```
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData));
```

This is the newer approach.
And don't give up :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting responses like this

```
Array ( [------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "mencommentid" 43 ------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mmencommentid" 39 ------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="replymencomment" asd ------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video" ------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="" Content-Type: application/octet-stream ------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="" Content-Type: application/octet-stream ------WebKitFormBoundaryZHCPkXfouoiFpLDg-- )
```

then

```
cache: false,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

adding these inside request helps me